# Command 'rebar doc' is inconsistent

Tags: erlang, rebar

First of all, 'rebar doc' works sometimes and sometimes not. It is strange.
Rebar version which I'm using is 2.5.1

My folder structure is:

1. Header_Directory
   1.1 apps
   1.1.1 sub_dir_1
   1.1.2 sub_dir_2 / include
   1.1.3 sub_dir_3
   1.2 deps
   1.3 confs
   rebar.config

Modules in sub_dir_3 also use some include files from sub_dir_2/include folder.

> The error I get when I use  the command rebar doc is:
>   .sub_dir_3/src/my_log_worker.erl, in module header: at line 9: file
>   not found: some.hrl   edoc: skipping source file
>   'sub_dir_3/src/my_log_worker.erl': {'EXIT',error}. edoc: error in
>   doclet 'edoc_doclet': {'EXIT',error}.   ERROR: doc failed while
>   processing /home/learn/header_directory/apps/sub_dir_3: {'EXIT',error}

I do 'rebar clean' and then 'rebar compile' prior to 'rebar doc'

Also,when I do it in erl shell, I get error.

> edoc:file("some_log_worker.erl", []).
>   edoc: error reading file 'some_log_worker.erl'.
>   ** exception exit: {error,enoent}
>         in function  edoc:read_source/2 (edoc.erl, line 664) 
>         in call from edoc_extract:source/3 (edoc_extract.erl, line 52)
>         in call from edoc:read/2 (edoc.erl, line 537)
>         in call from edoc:file/2 (edoc.erl, line 116)

Is there any way by which I can include my hrl file either in rebar.config or edoc options?

I have '{edoc_opts, [{ i, "apps/sub_dir_3/include" }]}.' in rebar.config, still of no help.

Comment: you probably want to look into formatting your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't follow the rebar/OTP conventions:

> OTP Conventions
>
> Rebar expects projects to follow the OTP conventions as described in
>   the OTP Design Principles document: Applications
>
> An application should consists of the following set of directories:
>
> ```
> src
> ebin
> priv
> include
> ```
>
> and have an application resource file: ebin/example_project.app or
>   src/example_project.app.src. In the later case, the
>   ebin/example_project.app file is generated from the
>   src/example_project.app.src one automatically during the compilation
>   phase.

[Rebar & OTP convetions](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Rebar-and-OTP-conventions)

I recommend you to move to that file organisation, it will be really much simpler to benefit from standard tools like rebar.

Comment: Yes, it is always in the best interest to follow the OTP principles. However, it worked for my app structure. The only problem was because of @headerfile annotation in the erlang modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is always in the best interest to follow the OTP principles. However, it worked for my app structure.

The only problem was because of @headerfile annotation in the erlang modules. Somehow, I don't know how to correctly use the @headerfile annotation.

Thanks for all the help. :)